# jQuery - Add a second var to select option field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select

i have the following JS Code:

```
//vars
    var plz = jQuery('#plz_field_12374786');
    var ortsteil = jQuery('#ortsteil_field_31289743');
    var is_ortsteil = jQuery('#is_ortsteil_12312487');

    //PLZ-Ajax for Ortsteil
    jQuery(plz).on('change', function(){
        var obj = jQuery(this);
        obj.addClass('loading');
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: '/xxxxxxx/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=get_ortsteil_from_plz&plz='+jQuery(this).val(),
            context: document.body
        }).done(function(data) {
            var ortsteile = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            jQuery(ortsteil).find('option').each(function(){
                jQuery(this).remove();
            });
            if(ortsteile.length>1){
                for (var i=0;i<ortsteile.length;i++){
                    jQuery('<option/>').val(ortsteile[i]).html(ortsteile[i]).appendTo(ortsteil);
                }
                jQuery(ortsteil).show();
                jQuery(ortsteil).attr('disabled', false);
                jQuery(is_ortsteil).val('true');
            }else{
                jQuery(ortsteil).hide();
                jQuery(ortsteil).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                jQuery(is_ortsteil).val('false');
            }
            obj.removeClass('loading');
        });
    });
```

The result is an select field like:

```
<select style="" class="ortsteil" id="ortsteil_field_31289743" name="ortsteil_field_31289743">
<option value="Districtname1">Districtname1</option>
<option value="Districtname2">Districtname2</option>
<option value="Districtname3">Districtname3</option>
</select>
```

I want to display the PLZ (zip-Code) too... like:

```
<select style="" class="ortsteil" id="ortsteil_field_31289743" name="ortsteil_field_31289743">
<option value="PLZ - Districtname1">PLZ - Districtname1</option>
<option value="PLZ - Districtname2">PLZ - Districtname2</option>
<option value="PLZ - Districtname3">PLZ - Districtname3</option>
</select>
```

Can someone help me and tell me what I have to change?

Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
jQuery('<option/>').val(ortsteile[i]).html(ortsteile[i]).appendTo(ortsteil);
```

to

```
jQuery('<option/>').val('PLZ - ' + ortsteile[i]).html('PLZ - ' + ortsteile[i]).appendTo(ortsteil);
```

Or if `PLZ -` is a variable, replace the string in the above with it:

```
jQuery('<option/>').val(plz + ' - ' + ortsteile[i]).html(plz + ' - ' + ortsteile[i]).appendTo(ortsteil);
```